# How can I use the dependency of the aar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I have a problem of using aar package in Android Studio Project.
Yesterday I wrote a Android Studio library called `xEditText`, adding a dependency like this:

*compile `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0`*

and then I build this library to an aar package.
When I use this aar package in my project like this:

*compile `xEditText-release`*

and run,I found it crashed,it was an 'Error inflating class' error.Later I got the answer，when I add the compiling in my project like this：

*compile `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0`*

it runs well.

But I don't know why that I have to compile the dependency `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0` what had compiled in my library to my project again?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know why that I have to compile the dependency(com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0) what had compiled in my library to my project again?

Because `xEditText` is a library, `nineoldandroids` becomes the  transitive dependency for any project which uses `xEditText`. Transitive dependencies are not icnluded in the output `aar` file by default.

You can fix this behavior by specifying that `nineoldandroid` should be included in the `xEditText` like so:

```
compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I am newbie in Android development.I tried as you say but it didn't work as well.Is it because that my aar package is output in the 'debug-mode'?I don't know why that there is only xEditText-debug.aar in the 'outputs--aar' folder.How can I generate a release type aar-package?

Comment: where did you put 'transitive = true' - inside the xEditText module, or inside the application module?